# NSubstitute received string mismatch

Tags: nsubstitute

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.CallNotReceivedException: Expected to receive call:   
  PromptForYesNo("Sums insured business interruption period is 653 month(s) longer than fire indemnity period.", any String)   
Actually received (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):   
  PromptForYesNo(*"Sums insured business interruption period is 653 month(s) longer than fire indemnity period.
"*, "Do you want to save?")
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?
To me the strings looks identical and they are, they come from the same object property.

I would appreciate some info on why this fails, thanks.

Comment: Assuming you've copy and pasted that accurately, the second one ends with a line-break that the first one doesn't - could that be it? If that's OK and you want to ignore it then you could try .Trim()ming the strings before you compare them.

Comment: You are correct, there is actually a line break there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a line break that I didn't notice.